# How to create Android browser history & bookmark

Tags: android

How to save or create browser history for android browser. every time when web view loads a page, browser history saves the link. & again how to create bookmark for browser
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you provide a bit more context with your question here?  Some of the code which you have tried which is not working?  As the question is currently stated, it is really difficult to understand what you are trying to do and what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the last url and make an array to store all the links user has viewed . Here is how you get the last url visited

```
 WebBackForwardList mWebBackForwardList = mWebView.copyBackForwardList();
 String historyUrl = mWebBackForwardList.getItemAtIndex(mWebBackForwardList.getCurrentIndex()-1).getUrl();
```

In similar fashion when user is viewing some link and when he clicks bookmark option get the url Loaded and save to array or something